# powermta don't send bounce back mail

Tags: email-bounces

I'm using powermta - port25 for bulk mailing. I want it to send bounce mail back to specific bounce back address.

Some servers send for quota or inactive user problem but i want to take all bounce mail report to bounce address. powermta creates logs for bounce mail.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

It is definetly possible to send back to bounce emails to spesific email.

There are two types of bounce messages in PoweMTA:

1-) Local bounce message: PowerMTA generates this messages if it gets any bounce message from remote ESP. Almost more than 90% of bounce messages generate this way. In this case you do not have to do anything. PowerMTA will send email that contains bounce information and bounce diagnostic messages to mail from email adress MX.

2-) Transient bounce message: This type of message does not generated by PowerMTA. When PowerMTA connects to remote server to deliver message, remote server accapts email without error than after a period of time, remote server will send bounce message directly to mail from address.

If you have add any configuration to discard the mail from domain. That is all different story.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to configure is `deliver-local-dsn`. This directive instructs PowerMTA whether or not to generate and deliver a
Delivery Status Notification (DSN) for a message.

```
<domain *>
    deliver-local-dsn no
</domain>
```

The bounce notifications are sent to `MAIL FROM` address. You can read more about it on Port25 blog post: [To where are bounce messages sent?](https://port25.com/to-where-are-bounce-messages-sent/)

Answer (score -2):

My understanding is power mta cannot do this functionality.